# Как из одной таблицы выбрать строку с максимальным id для каждой категории?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!
Есть таблица, в которой есть столбец с идентификатором категории.
Нужно выбрать строки с максимальным значением id по каждой категории, чтобы потом вывести в цикле. То есть выбрать последнюю статью каждой категории.
Сделать четырьмя запросами могу, но это как-то по-колхозному. Как сделать выборку одним запросом не знаю... Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например вот так:

```
SELECT category, MAX(id)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY category
```

UPD видимо не сразу понял, что вы хотите. Вот обновленный вариант, который вернет всю строку целиком:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT category, MAX(id) AS id
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Category       
) t2 ON t1.category = t2.category AND t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: То есть, если у меня, допустим, 4 категории, то данный запрос выберет по одной строке каждой из категорий с максимальным id и в массиве окажется 4 строки? Мне кажется, тут только два столбца захватятся или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: сейчас дополню, секунду

Comment: Ого! Спасибо! Не совсем понятно с t1 t2 - это что-то наподобие маркеров?

Comment: ну это псевдонимы для таблицы MyTable (также называются алиасами). Они позволяют понять, к какой именно таблице из участвующих в операции join вы обращаетесь

Answer (score 0):

Кроме указанного есть ещё как минимум 4 способа.
Рекомендую посмотреть эту статью: [**Группировка в MySQL**](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)