# Как найти связанные записи с максимальной датой?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица recipients и recipient_history. В таблице recipients есть такие поля как:

- RECIPIENT_ID,
- RECIPIENT_NAME

а в таблице recipient_history:

- RECIPIENT_ID,
- START_DATE,
- END_DATE
- JOB_NAME,
- DEPARTAMENT_ID.

Мне надо вывести имя и последнее место роботы сотрудника. Надо учитывать что в таблице recipient_history один и тот же сотрудник может встречаться дважды и с разными JOB_NAME.

Например

`RECIPIENT_ID[1|1|2], START_DATE[12.03.2012|12.03.2015|15.04.2012], END_DATE[12.03.2014|12.03.2016|12.03.2013], JOB_NAME[it_spec,it_prog, manager],
DEPARTAMENT_ID[101,102,103]`

Comment: выберите max(END_DATE) сгрупируйте по  RECIPIENT_ID и присоидените ecipient_history ещёраз по даным двум полям.

Comment: я примерно так сделал но не получается

Comment: можете по подробнее

Comment: А SQL какой ? у sql-server есть красивый вариант с оконными функциями например. В MySQL решается другими методами, например как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412928/  И таких ответов тут кстати куча, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Bmysql%5D+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, без вложенных запросов не обойдешься.

```
SELECT
    R.RECIPIENT_NAME AS RECIPIENT_NAME,
    IFNULL(RH2.JOB_NAME,'') AS JOB_NAME
FROM
    recipients R
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
        RECIPIENT_ID,
        MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE
    FROM
        recipient_history RH
    GROUP BY
        RECIPIENT_ID
    ) RH ON RH.RECIPIENT_ID = R.RECIPIENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN recipient_history RH2 ON RH.END_DATE = RH2.END_DATE AND RH.RECIPIENT_ID = RH2.RECIPIENT_ID
ORDER BY
    RH.END_DATE DESC;
```

Вложенные запросы - зло, они порождают временные таблицы при обработке запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо

1. В таблице `recipient_history` найти записи с максимальной датой.
2. Результат этой выборки объединить с `recipient`.

Пункт (2) не составляет труда. Как найти (1) ? Есть несколько способов.

- Один из них предложил @ArtemAleksashkin: сгруппировать, найти максимальную дату и по этой дате объединить с этой же таблицей чтобы получить строку целиком.
- Грязный трюк, использующий "особенность" MySQL: с дефолтными настройками он допускает группировку с выводом всех полей, а не только группируемых + агрегаты. Надо только обеспечить нужный нам порядок (решение фу, я считаю):

  SELECT * FROM
  (
   SELECT * FROM `recipient_history`
   ORDER BY `END_DATE` DESC
  ) t1
  GROUP BY `RECIPIENT_ID`
- Открытое самообъединение со сравнением на больше/меньше и отсечкой по NULL:

  SELECT o.*
  FROM `recipient_history` o
    LEFT JOIN `recipient_history` b
        ON o.`RECIPIENT_ID` = b.`RECIPIENT_ID`
       AND o.`END_DATE` < b.`END_DATE`
  WHERE b.`END_DATE` is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте обычный запрос, просто добавьте в конце

```
ORDER BY `END_DATE` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: «Обычный запрос» это какой?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT 
      r.RECIPIENT_NAME, h.START_DATE, h.END_DATE, h.JOB_NAME
    FROM
      recipients r, recipient_history h
    WHERE
      r.RECIPIENT_ID = h.RECIPIENT_ID AND
      h.START_DATE = (SELECT MAX(h2.START_DATE) FROM recipient_history h2 WHERE r.RECIPIENT_ID = h2.RECIPIENT_ID)`