# SQL запрос на выборку из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Существует две таблицы: `dialog(id,firstname)` и `message(id, dialog_id, text, time)`. Необходимо выбрать все записи dialog, при этом к каждой записи dialog выбрать последнюю запись message, относящаяся к этому dialog

---

dialog.id   | dialog.firstname  |  message.text  |  message.time

---

Прошу вашей помощи, камрады.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545054

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576996/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего сложного. Присоединяем, как мостик, к таблице `dialog` к каждой записи последний `id` из таблицы `message`, затем присоединяем остальные поля:

```
select d.*, mess.text, mess.time
from dialog d left join
    (select dialog_id, max(id) as max_id /*либо max(time)*/
     from message 
     group by dialog_id) m ON d.id = m.dialog_id
    join message mess ON m.max_id = mess.id
```

Comment: Работает, но повозившись пришел к такому варианту = SELECT chat.id, message.time, message.text FROM chat,message WHERE message.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM message WHERE message.chat_id = chat.id) GROUP BY chat.id ORDER BY message.id DESC

Comment: @Vladislav у вас он точно работает? Group by лишний, подзапросы частенько работают дольше, чем джоины

Comment: как ни странно, но работает запрос правильно, а насчет быстроты - учту