# sql запрос не выводить похожие записи

Tags: sql

Есть таблица допустим id|user|text|time нужно скрыть похожие записи по полю user c **сортировкой по time** делаю так `SELECT * FROM tabl GROUP BY user ORDER BY time` похожие записи скрываются, но не работает ORDER BY time, что есть что нет его. думаю что сортируются по первым записям, а нужно по последним

Comment: Для начала ознакомьтесь например с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-group-by-%D0%B2-mysql тогда разберетесь, что после group by сортировка по time уже бесполезна, потому что в time не предсказуемое значение. и тогда можете попробовать сортировать например по `max(time)` только `select *` в сочетании с group by вообще недопустим, потому что все поля кроме user становятся непредсказуемыми и надо явно описывать что с каждым из них делать

Comment: После этого, когда разберетесь, что же вам нужно делать с остальными полями, если вам например понадобятся записи с максимальной датой, воспользуйтесь например этим подходом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412928/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-id-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Опишите целиком вашу задачу.